# Analyse beat intensity

Tags: python, audio

I'm trying to work on a machine learning application, and I need to analyze a .wav file and retrieve the "intensity" of each beat.

You know when you look at the waves of a .wav file, and some beats are bigger than the other (or taller)? How do I analyse that, and get those values as numbers with timestamps?

I tried looking into the Aubio library, but I'm not sure if it'd help me a lot, it's not that well documented.

I didn't really write any code, just been researching into this, and I'd appreciate if someone could give me a step in the right direction.

Comment: then start learning step by step. I had similar experience when I wanted to learn processing but I only ended up editing existing code and didn't really understand for loops or anything. I think that the key point in your question is *I didn't really write any code*, what does that mean? How far have you gone?

Comment: @Jansindl3r I've writen code before, I mean about this topic I didn't write any code to provide in the question, just been researching about it.